# Library source does not match the bytecode for class ImaAdsLoader using ExoPlayer

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

While displaying ads with IMA extension and the ProgressiveMediaSource, I am getting the following error. The app crashed just after the preroll ad completes.
On navigating to the class ImaAdsLoader I get the error "Library source does not match the bytecode for class ImaAdsLoader"

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getAdGroupIndexAfterPositionUs(J)I in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ads/AdPlaybackState; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdPlaybackState' appears in /data/app/com.example.exomedia-pEwo-P6MjYGRL3PeKbTLiw==/base.apk)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.ima.ImaAdsLoader.getContentProgress(ImaAdsLoader.java:758)
        at com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.internal.iu.a(IMASDK:4)
        at com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.internal.jh.handleMessage(IMASDK:27)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)`

Steps to reproduce : 
    Use the following depencies

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.9.6'`

And initiate the playback with the following code:

```
   player=ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,DefaultTrackSelector())
    player_view.player=player
    adsLoader?.setPlayer(player)


    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
        this,
        "ExoDemo")

    val mediaSource:MediaSource=ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(resources.getString(R.string.media_url_mp4)))

    val adsMediaSource = AdsMediaSource(mediaSource, dataSourceFactory, adsLoader, player_view)


    player?.prepare(adsMediaSource)
    player?.setPlayWhenReady(true)
```

The works without any error with the following versions of the libraries and using ExtractorMediaSource:

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.9.6'`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the version of the extension_ima must match the version of the ExoPlayer library being used.
Alternatively, one can clone the ExoPlayer repository and depend on the module locally.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ima